# ndk opengles 2.0 blurred screen in moto/mtk platform but ok with samsung

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

My small game is completed, but I test it with samsung galaxy s3 always and it's ok always.

Today, I test it in a moto me865 device, the game screen is blurred. Then, I tested more devices, it is ok with nexus7/htc and windows(glew2), but failed with MTK/RK/Omap...

The render engine of my game is powered by myself, it is very sample, pure 2d, only one texture layer, ortho projection, the complex data type is rect with rotation...

I dont know how to fixing this problem now, who can give me some stuff or hints? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two sources of the problem, first is different aspect ratios of the screen and on those that do not match your device ratio stretching would occur.

Another thing is magnification/minification. When you rendering texture and your pixels are not stirctly map to texels some distortions are inevitable, what can help abit to fix blurness is to use GL_NEAREST filter.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

for best results you should have separate texture for each resolution or somehow extend engine to allow pixel to texel rendering by fitting less or more objects depending on screen.